# AutoComplete(MUI) I am trying to set a default Value in the checkbox from an API, but getting (intermediate value).filter is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here is my code, I need get a default value from the API inside the checkbox initially, I used Material-UI Autocomplete component, though it has defaultValue prop, Even after trying that got the same error. But I can able get the API data as listed options.

```
import React from "react"
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox"
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core"
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField"
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form"
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete"
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBoxOutlineBlank"
import CheckBoxIcon from "@material-ui/icons/CheckBox"

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />

export default function StoreFilter({ data, onStoreChange }) {

  // data is the state passed from my parent component
  // data contains the API response
  const [defaultStore, setDefaultStore] = React.useState("")

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (data.length > 0) {
        setDefaultStore(data[0].name)
      }
    }, 2000)
  }, [data])

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container style={{ justifyContent: "flex-end" }}>
        <Grid item style={{ marginTop: "15px", marginBottom: "20px" }}>
                <Autocomplete
                  multiple
                  id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
                  onChange={(event, value) => {
                    onStoreChange(value)
                    setDefaultStore(null)
                  }}
                  options={data}
                  disableCloseOnSelect
                  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                  getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
                  defaultValue={defaultStore}
                  renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                      <Checkbox
                        icon={icon}
                        checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                        style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                        checked={selected}
                      />
                      {option.name}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  )}
                  style={{ width: 550 }}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      {...params}
                      variant="outlined"
                      label="Stores"
                      placeholder="More..."
                    />
                  )}
                />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  )
}
```

**My objective is to get default values in the checkbox initially.**

I'm getting this error even while defaultValue Props from AutoComplete

TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).filter is not a function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array.Filter` in the `Array` state:

```
setDefaultStore(ArrayData.filter(data => data.id === idYourFinding))
```